# How to view a field variable content in visual studio editor in design time when i do mouseover

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, code-editor

Question is simple. I just want to know what's in the variable value(those are actually constants or have default value) in design time -NOT RUNTIME or WHILE DEBUGGING- in the Visual Studio editor instead of scrolling to variable itself to see field's content?

Is there any feature, extension or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a value and don't need to change it, you can directly define it as a constant. This way you can see the value directly when you hover over it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt know if i'd define the variable as const it would be seen from other places. 
I wrote it as const in the question description but i've not tried it before. 
I ve tried it for readonly but not for const.